# Validation message and focus dissapearing fast on jquery ajax script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I am trying to validate a form via jquery but after I hit the submit button the message appears, focus works, but only for 1 ms after message disappears and field looses focus.

Jquery Ajax

```
$(document).on('submit','.subscribe',function(e) {
var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
var name = $("#sname").val();
var email = $("#semail").val();
if( name == "" ) {
    $("#submess").html('Please enter your name in the required field to proceed.');
    $("#sname").focus();
}
else if( email == "" ) {
    $("#submess").html('Please enter your email address in the required email field to proceed. Thanks.');
    $("#email").focus();
}
else if(reg.test(email) == false) {
    $("#submess").html('Sorry, your email address is invalid. Please enter a valid email address to proceed. Thanks.');
    $("#email").focus();
} 
else 
{
  e.preventDefault(); // add here
  e.stopPropagation(); // add here
  $.ajax({ url: 'lib/common-functions.php',
    data: {action: 'subscribe',
        sname: $("#sname").val(),
        semail: $("#semail").val()},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(output) {
        $("#submess").html(output);
    }
 });
}
});
```

HTML

```
   <form name="subscribe" class="subscribe">
    <div id="submess"></div>
    <label class="lablabel">Name:</label><input type="text" class="subscribe-field" id="sname" name="sname"></br>
    <label class="lablabel">Email:</label><input type="text" class="subscribe-field" id="semail" name="semail"> 
    <input type="submit" id="ssub" value="Subscribe">
  </form>
```

Where am i mistaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
  e.preventDefault();
```

After

```
$(document).on('submit','.subscribe',function(e) {
```

Your page is reloading, that's the problem.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('submit','.subscribe',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // some more stuff
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asheshambasta/fEzva/)